# match string between columns using perl

Tags: perl, string-matching

I want to compare a string in column A with that in column B for every row and print a third column that highlights the differences.

```
Column A                      Column B
uuaaugcuaauugugauaggggu       uuaaugcuaauugugauaggggu
uuaaugcuaauugugauagggguu      uuaaugcuaauugugauaggggu
uuaaugcuaauugugauagggguuu     uuaaugcuaauugugauaggggu
```

Desired Result:

```
Column A                      Column B                Column C
uuaaugcuaauugugauaggggu       uuaaugcuaauugugauaggggu ********************
uuaaugcuaauugugauagggguu      uuaaugcuaauugugauaggggu ********************u
uuaaugcuaauugugauagggguuu     uuaaugcuaauugugauaggggu ********************uu
```

I have an example script that might work, but how do I do this for every row in the data frame?

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $string1 = 'AAABBBBBCCCCCDDDDD';
my $string2 = 'AEABBBBBCCECCDDDDD';
my $result = '';
for(0 .. length($string1)) {
    my $char = substr($string2, $_, 1);
    if($char ne substr($string1, $_, 1)) {
        $result .= "**$char**";
    } else {
        $result .= $char;
    }
}
print $result;
```

Comment: There is a problem that it is hard to imagine *"a third column that highlights the differences"*. If the first two columns were `ABC` and `ABD` then the "difference" would be that the first column has `C` in the third position whereas the first has `D`. Unless the second string alwaysstarts with the contents of the first string, it is hard to express this difference in a single string, and you should say what you need.

Comment: Suppose the first column contains `uuaaug` and the second column contains `gggacc`, what third column would wish to see?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not resist to provide a modified Miller's solution with regular expressions

```
   use strict;
   use warnings;

   while (<DATA>) {
    my $masked_str1 ="";
    my $masked_str2 ="";
    my ($str1, $str2) = split;

    my $intersection = $str1 ^ $str2;
    while ($intersection =~ /(\x00+)/g) {

        my $mask = $intersection;
        $mask =~ s/\x00/1/g;
        $mask =~ s/[^1]/0/g;

        while ( $mask =~ /\G(.)/gc ) { # traverse the mask
           my $bit = $1;
           if ( $str1 =~ /\G(.)/gc ) { # traverse the string1 to be masked
                $masked_str1 .= $bit ? '_' : $1;
           }
           if ( $str2 =~ /\G(.)/gc ) { # traverse the string2 to be masked
                $masked_str2 .= $bit ? '_' : $1;
           }
        }

    }
    print "=" x 80;
    printf "\n%-30s %s\n", $str2, $str1; # Minimum length 30 char, left-justified
    printf "%-30s %s\n", $str1, $str2;  
    printf "%-30s %s\n\n", $masked_str1, $masked_str2;  


}
```

Comment: @user3741035 Readability matters more than speed, so pick your favorite.  However, this method is 3 times slower than my substr solution, and 10 times slower than my alternative xor solution:  [`benchmarks`](http://ideone.com/kzmTBS)

Comment: It was for me just a regex exercise. Thank you for your benchmarks.

Answer (score 2):

Using bruteforce and [`substr`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/substr.html)

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {
    my ($str1, $str2) = split;
    my $len = length $str1 < length $str2 ? length $str1 : length $str2;
    for my $i (0..$len-1) {
        my $c1 = substr $str1, $i, 1;
        my $c2 = substr $str2, $i, 1;
        if ($c1 eq $c2) {
            substr $str1, $i, 1, '*';
            substr $str2, $i, 1, '*';
        }
    }
    printf "%-30s %s\n", $str1, $str2;
}

__DATA__
Column_A                      Column_B
uuaaugcuaauugugauaggggu       uuaaugcuaauugugauaggggu
uuaaugcuaauugugauagggguu      uuaaugcuaauugugauaggggu
uuaaugcuaauugugauagggguuu     uuaaugcuaauugugauaggggu
AAABBBBBCCCCCDDDDD            AEABBBBBCCECCDDDDD
```

Outputs:

```
*******A                       *******B
***********************        ***********************
***********************u       ***********************
***********************uu      ***********************
*A********C*******             *E********E*******
```

**Alternative using XOR**

It's also possible to use `^` to find the intersection between two strings.

The following performs the same as the above:

```
while (<DATA>) {
    my ($str1, $str2) = split;

    my $intersection = $str1 ^ $str2;
    while ($intersection =~ /(\0+)/g) {
        my $len = length $1;
        my $pos = pos($intersection) - $len;
        substr $str1, $pos, $len, '*' x $len;
        substr $str2, $pos, $len, '*' x $len;
    }

    printf "%-30s %s\n", $str1, $str2;
}
```

Comment: Hmm. I got this error: Can't locate object method "UUAAUGCUAAUUGUGAUAGGGGU" via package "UUAAUGCUAAUUGUGAUAGGGGUU" (perhaps you forgot to load "UUAAUGCUAAUUGUGAUAGGGGUU"?) at isomir_test.csv line 1

Comment: @user3741035: Well? Did you load `UUAAUGCUAAUUGUGAUAGGGGUU`?!

Comment: @user3741035: I'm sorry - I was joking. I hoped the "!" would have told you so. I can't see anything there that could be misconstrued as a method call, and I think you must be trying to execute the CSV file as if it were a Perl script?

Comment: Thanks! Indeed I did execute the csv instead of the script :))